hapi-fhir-7.0.0 is missing FHIRPathEngine
I have a large code base written over about 5 years now successfully using HAPI FHIR in a great number of functional ways. I'm using the following JARs which, until just after 6.10.5 (February 2024), offered FHIRPathEngine:
hapi-fhir-base
hapi-fhir-structures-r4
hapi-fhir-validation-resources-r4
hapi-fhir-validation

I have just tried to update HAPI FHIR JARs to be more recent. It appears that hapi-fhir-7.x is missing the FHIRPathEngine symbol altogether. Also, symbol JsonLikeValue went missing in the later 6.x time frame.
After much Googling and some experimentation I have not been able to a) add to my JAR suite nor b) find wisdom on what to do about these missing symbols (except that I stopped using JsonLikeValue).

It turns out that the package path for FHIRPathEngine has changed since 6.10.5 and 7.x:
org.hl7.fhir.r4.utils.FHIRPathEngine     (old)
org.hl7.fhir.r4.fhirpath.FHIRPathEngine  (current)

